# GIDSignIn.sharedInstance : sharedInstance not a function?

Tags: swift, google-signin

In this code, when I type GIDSignIn.sharedInstance, for some reason sharedInstance is not a function, which means I can't acces clientID. I cannot find a solution for this anywhere.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn


@main

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "clientID"
        
          return true
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
}

Comment: Also it could be an Xcode error too, sometimes Xcode refuses to recognise things like this. You can restart it or just clean the build and rebuild it with the other above suggestions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In latest version of GoogleSignIn SDK. Removed this method.

Now in new follow this link or below code.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in

```
@IBAction func clkLoginWithGmail(_ sender: UIButton) {
     let signInConfig = GIDConfiguration.init(clientID: "clientID-XYZ")
     GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: signInConfig, presenting: self) { user, error in

     }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much, it worked. Any idea why this change?

Answer (score 3):

There is a change in the dependency.

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.clientID
```

Has been changed to:

```
GIDConfiguration(clientID: "clientID", serverClientID: "serverClientID")
```

And can be used in your class or AppDelegate.swift

```
import GoogleSignIn

let gIdConfiguration = GIDConfiguration(clientID: "clientID", serverClientID: "serverClientID")

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.configuration = gIdConfiguration
```